# Unable to create Live usb pen

Tags: usb

I know there are tons of post about this already and i have read most of them.
but still they don't answer my question.

As said above i am trying to create a bootable usb pen with ubuntu 12 on it
i have use the linux usb creator

got a error that it's unable to boot the kernel

i used LILI

got a error that it's unable to boot the kernel

i renanemd some files on the stick

got a error that it's unable to boot the kernel

and i know the stick ( intenso 32 gb ) is up to the job
there was a backtrack version on it before

but even with that i had loads of troubel there was one post
that solved my problem but i can't find that post anymore

it was about creating a active partition on the usb pen
so the computer would see it as a hard drive en then installing
linux on it like i would install it on a hd.

i can't even find a live cd version that i download and can run
of cd (' don't have a checksum program anymore on my windows)
i am running windows 8

looking forward to your replies

kind regards Nigel

Answer (score 0):

A few things you could try if you haven't already:

- you can try [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/), an other program to make live usb sticks
  for multiple linux distros
- you can try to re download your immage in case your download is
  corrputed
- if you have an other USB laying arround you can check whether that one works (if only to see where the problem is at.